# Camera gets locked randomly Android

Tags: android, background, camera

I am using Media Recorder to record videos in background without displaying a preview at one of my Activities. It works fine but randomly the camera gets locked and the only way to unlock it is to re-start the phone.

Can we find whether the camera is locked?
How can it be unlocked?
In case the App crashes how can the camera be released?

```
mCamera.startPreview();
```

Sometimes the code stops at the above line of code and finally ANR is displayed.

Comment: be sure to call mCamera.release() after use....

Comment: Yes, I do call mCamera.release() when i finish my Activity. But still it randomly locks the Camera. And the ANR appears the very first time when i try to start video recording and this issue is more common in Samsung devices.

Comment: You have to call release every time You stop the camera, not only if the activity is closed. So finally, it will be good to see the logcat output.

Comment: The functionality is as soon as the user enters the screen, video recording starts automatically. It records videos of 2 minute duration. So for example if your activity was alive for 20mins, 10 videos of 2mins each would be recorded.

Comment: ok, so please could You post the logcat?

Comment: CRASH: STACK_TRACE=java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)                                      ANR: at android.hardware.Camera.startPreview(Native Method)
at com.drivermaticsapp.android.service.RecordBackgroundGPSDataService.startMediaRecording(RecordBackgroundGPSDataService.java:776)
at com.drivermaticsapp.android.service.RecordBackgroundGPSDataService$1.dispatchMessage(RecordBackgroundGPSDataService.java:276)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)

Comment: can You post the full source code RecordBackgroundGPSDataService ?

Comment: After a month, trying all the possibilities I fixed this issue. The issue was related to hardware when you try to access and release the Camera continuously at one stage the native methods become unresponsive and locks the camera. I used camera.reconnect() to access the camera recursively.